# Selectize.js load callback pass-through to custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, selectize.js

I have configured [selectize.js](https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) to gather configuration options from html data attributes. One of my configuration types is the ability to specify a js function to call for custom data loading (outside simple ajax loading). The code is working well, until I run a custom function that is asynchronous. With asynchronous methods in use, the selectize.js load callback returns before the data has been loaded. I have been struggling to find a way to pass the selectize.js load() callback through to the custom load function.

Here is a select element configured to run the "loadStates()" function to get data for this specific select element:

```
<select
    id="state"
    class="selectize"
    data-load-type="callback"
    data-load-callback="loadStates"
>
```

Here is the "loadStates()" function to be called. I have kept it simple for this example, but ideally this could be any kind of method, including asynchronous methods.

```
<script>
    function loadStates(searchQuery) {
        return {
            "states": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "abbr": "AK",
                    "description": "Alaska"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "abbr": "CA",
                    "description": "California"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "abbr": "OR",
                    "description": "Oregon"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "abbr": "WA",
                   "description": "Washington"
                }
            ]
        };
    }
</script>
```

Last, here is my anonymous function being passed to the selectize.js load method.

```
// Get custom load function from select element data attribute
var loadCallback = $(this).attr('data-load-callback');

// The selectize.js load option needs an anonymous function with two
// arguments, query and callback. This function should return the data.
var _load = function(query, callback) {

    // Call the custom load function
    callback(window[loadCallback](query));
};

// Pass the _load configuration to selectize
$(this).selectize({load: _load});
```

This all works great with the simple loadStates() function. However, as soon as I add something asynchronous, the selectize.js load() callback is returned too soon.

**What I'v tried :**

I tried sending the load() callback into the custom function like this:

```
// ...

// Call the custom load function
window[loadCallback](query, callback);

// ...

function loadStates(searchQuery, callback) {
    callback( 
        // ... json data here
    );
}
```

However, no data was returned.

**Update - Using @thewildpendulum solution:**

So there is this [load](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#callbacks) option with selectize, which is different then the load() API method. However, they both work the same (expect data to be returned) so no real difference for purposes of this question.

I had somewhat simplified my code above, I'll make a note to not do that in the future. I also have two optional parameters the user can specify to slice the data to a smaller selection specifying a key in the data returned, and/or a record limit. I think I have a good solution provided by a coworker. I would appreciate any feedback if there is a better way.

New callbacks object as suggested, adding two load parameter properties

```
// callbacks object for custom user provided data methods
var callbacks = {
    loadKey:    null,
    loadLimit:  0,
    loadStates: function (query, selectizeCallback) {
      var data = {
        "states": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "abbr": "AK",
            "description": "Alaska"
          },
          {
              "id": 2,
              "abbr": "CA",
              "description": "California"
          },
          {
              "id": 3,
              "abbr": "OR",
              "description": "Oregon"
          },
          {
              "id": 4,
              "abbr": "WA",
              "description": "Washington"
          }
        ]
      };
      if (null !== this.loadKey) {
        selectizeCallback(data[this.loadKey].slice(0, this.loadLimit));
      }
      else {
        selectizeCallback(data.slice(0, this.loadLimit));
      }
    }
  }
```

New code for building selectize load option with user callback object and custom data slicing

```
// Set load parameters (gather these values from html data attr earlier)
callbacks.loadKey   = loadKey;
callbacks.loadLimit = loadLimit;

// Build load option
var _load = callbacks[loadCallback].bind(callbacks);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. The [selectize documentation](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_other) states:

> load(fn) - Loads options by invoking the the provided function. The function should accept one argument (callback) and invoke the callback with the results once they are available.

The important part here is that selectize doesn't care where or how the data is obtained. Fetching the data can happen synchronously or asynchronously because all it cares about is the argument to `callback()`.

This point gets a bit confused in your code, but you can still see it at work there. Your `_load()` function does exactly what it's supposed to do by taking the callback argument. However, the custom function returns its value directly. While this isn't wrong to do, it gets you thinking the wrong way.

```
// Get custom load function from select element data attribute
var loadCallbackSync = $(this).attr('data-load-callback');

// we have this wrapper function that calls our custom load function
var _load = function(query, callback) {
    var result = window[loadCallbackSync](query);
    // -> returns our result

    callback( result );
};

// if we take the same approach with async loading...
var loadCallbackAsync = $(this).attr('data-load-callback');

var _load = function(query, callback) {
    var result = window[loadCallbackAsync](query);
    // -> oh noes!

    callback( result );
};
```

Despite the common patterns of synchronous functions `return`ing their data and asynchronous functions using `callback()`s, all we really need to do is get data into selectize's callback function. As it turns out, you don't need `_load()` at all. You can simply write your custom functions such that they can be used directly by selectize.

(I wasn't able to find any reference in selectize to a `load()` function that accepts a `query` argument. However, including it or removing is trivial.)

```
var callbacks = {
    loadStatesSync: function (query, selectizeCallback) {
        var states = [
            // ...
        ];
        var result = doSomethingWithQuery(states, query);

        selectizeCallback(result);
    },
    loadStatesAsync: function (query, selectizeCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            // do something with query...,
            success: function (result) {
                selectizeCallback(result);
            }
        });
    }
}

var fnName = $(this).data('load-callback');
var _load  = callbacks[fnName];

$(this).selectize({load: _load});
```

It's easy to get asynchronous concepts conflated with using callbacks, but I hope this helped clear that up a bit!

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. One issue I'm having is I oversimplified my code here for this example, probably not smart in hindsight. In my actual code, I was also using two optional parameters that allow the user to specify a "key" in the returned data, and also a limit on the number of records to be returned. Something like:

callback(window[loadCallback](query)[loadKey].slice(0, loadLimit));

Since I would now have an anonymous function declaration, apposed to returned data, this method of slicing the data will not work. Is there any way to get these parameters in?

Comment: I can't offer much help without seeing the code, but there are a number of ways to do it. At the most basic level, though, you just need to make sure that whatever variables you have that will influence the final result are in scope of your various load functions. Then you can access those variables in your load functions to modify your states data. You can get a sense of this on the line `var result = doSomethingWithQuery(states, query);`. If `query` was in scope as part of a closure rather than being passed into that function, you'd be able to use to change what gets loaded into selectize.

Comment: I updated my original question with how I decided to solve the issue for now.